# Openlayers 3 attribution - source/ credit

Tags: openlayers

I can't get attribution (source/ credit) to show up for WMS layers added to and OL3 map. 
The attribution for base layers (OSM etc) works fine but when I try and use the attribution parameter to add attribution to my WMS layers no attribution shows up - any ideas?

```
        }),
        title:"Special Protection Areas",
        opacity:"0.4",
        attribution: "where it came from"
      })
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question: do you use a string for the `opacity` in the layer options. Use a number: `opacity: 0.4`.

Comment: yes looking at it I do, interestingly it works but I have fixed it. I Struggle with js a bit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The attributions should be set on the source. So, in the case of an `TileWMS` source, it will look like this:

```js
var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    attributions: [new ol.Attribution({
      html: "Where it came from"
    })]
  })
})
```

See this example for example: http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/wms-custom-proj.html.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct.